# Stack Egg - Force restart only if restart gains majority vote (at least 66% of total votes)

Tags: feature-request, stackegg

Tested this out on several sites with little activity/progress in the StackEgg game, so no harm done.

Restarting can occur as long as you have either majority vote on second vote or top vote (even if tie).

Make it so that a restart REQUIRES a majority vote. Meaning 50-50 will not restart.

Hell, even on the stackegg sites that have a lot of users, making it 2/3rds majority can easily root out the bots auto casting restart votes.

Simplest way to deal with the "Restart" abusers.